# Firefox extension to block arbitrary content using regular expressions

Tags: linux, android, open-source, firefox, regex

Needed: a Firefox extension/script to filter out unwanted content (all GET requests including those done through redirects: documents, scripts, iframes, pictures, any MIME type, actually).

Already checked out Schuzak's [SilentBlock](http://www.schuzak.jp) - not really working, cumbersome editing without a GUI.

Features required:

- Open source
- Gratis
- No 'dial home' features
- Reliable work under Linux and Android
- A simple GUI allowing adding new/editing existing regex'es in the browser

Optional features:

- A list of sample regexes to filter out common ads.
- Whitelist regexes.
- Ability to fire certain blacklist/whitelist regexes based on the main document's address (e.g. allowing Google APIs on one site and disallowing it on others).

Note: ideally, the extension should prevent the browser from accessing the blocked resource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

hmm I can't think of anything that does *exactly* what I *think* you want to do.

However I have a *pretty close* option; [Adblock Plus](https://adblockplus.org/en).

To go over your requirements:

- *Open source:* Yes.
- *Gratis:* Yes.
- *No 'dial home' features:* auto-updating is the norm for Firefox extensions; that can be disabled in Firefox; Adblock Plus also has filter lists that can be set to auto-update but that can be disabled as well. Other than those two caveats as far as I know ABP doesn't have any dial home functions.
- *Reliable work under Linux and Android:* I haven't run it on anything other than Linux (Firefox) or Windows (Firefox and Chrome) but it is very reliable under those circumstances and I would expect it to be fine for other situations - it is advertised for Android at least.
- *A simple GUI allowing adding new/editing existing regex'es in the browser*: I'd say it is pretty simple and easy.

Optional features:

- *A list of sample regexes to filter out common ads:* Yes there are a bunch available - options of what one(s) to install are included in the install process.
- *Whitelist regexes:* Yep white listing is done
- *Ability to fire certain blacklist/whitelist regexes based on the main document's address (e.g. allowing Google APIs on one site and disallowing it on others).* *hmmm...* ah [Yes you can](https://adblockplus.org/en/filters#elemhide_domains).

Adblock Plus is not limited to *GET* requests and I don't think there is any switch on the rules to only apply to GET requests but I think it should still work well. It uses JavaScript Regexes - [MDN docs should be helpful](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Writing_a_Regular_Expression_Pattern).

Comment: Ain't bare bones, and sold out to advertisers (a.k.a. Acceptable Ads), but I'm looking into its fork [AdBlock Edge](https://bitbucket.org/adstomper/adblockedge/downloads) :)

Comment: Personally I have no problem with the 'Acceptable Ads' - they are disableable and since I now have highspeed I am willing to support sites that I use if they want ads in a non-annoying manner. For that matter I disable ABP on many sites that I get a lot of value from but are otherwise free that I know use per-view paying advertisers.

Comment: Don't forget [Element Hiding Helper for Adblock Plus](http://adblockplus.org/en/elemhidehelper).

Comment: Oh yeah forgot about that - never use it myself as I'm just as comfortable just using Firebug/source view but definitely a good option for less sourcecode interested users

Comment: Turns out AdBlock Edge may be used more or less as required if a) I cancel all subscriptions, b) add regexes through the GUI or into the `patterns.ini` file, c) delete all the content (except the first line) of `elemhide.css`.

Comment: Will accept since ABE isn't worth a separate answer yet.